# A confusing GeneratorType implementation with while loop & let keyword

Tags: swift

I am confused trying to understand why do we use `let` keyword when we implementing Fibonacci generator.

```
struct FibonacciGenerator: GeneratorType {
typealias Element = Int

var values = (0, 1)

mutating func next() -> Element? {
    self.values = (
        self.values.1,
        self.values.0 + self.values.1
    )
    return self.values.0
    }
}

var generator = FibonacciGenerator()
while let next = generator.next() {
if next > 10 {
    break
}
print(next)
}
```

Why do we use `let` and not `var` in the `while` loop (before the next statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` should be used when defining a constant, meaning the value may not be changed afterwards, which is the case here.
If you were to modify `next` at any point, it would have to be declared as variable using the `var` keyword.

Comment: Did you actually read my question? next modified by generate method every loop , thus next object changes to a new value , let keyword means that next object can't change value. So i think i cant realize some idea, if somebody know what is going on with next object(or variable or constant i dont even know how to name it now) please ask me.

Comment: You are re-declaring the `next` constant over and over again until `generator.next()` does not return a non-optional value anymore. You are never changing the value of `next`. Make sure you understand the difference between declaring a variable/constant and assigning a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's optional binding in a while loop. next() returns an optional. You're missing a bit of code there, but it's just saying "while next is still returning a non nil value, do this stuff". You don't change x in the while loop, so no var declaration needed. I'm not even sure if you can use var in that situation. It's kind of confusing that they also named the variable next. You could have said

```
while let nextValue = next(){...}
```